# Multiple Async Operations in not working in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an async method in which I need to get multiple items of ViewBag data.

The problem is when I debug the code it works fine, and without debugging it doesn't load last view bag.

Here is sample code

**Method 1:**

```
public async Task LoadDDL()
{
        var baseCurrencyTask = GetBaseCurrencyAsync();
        var remittanceCurrencyTask = GetRemittanceCurrencyAsync();
        var branchRemiCountryTask = GetBranchRemCountryAsync();
        await Task.WhenAll(baseCurrencyTask, remittanceCurrencyTask, branchRemiCountryTask);

        ViewBag.BaseCurrency = baseCurrencyTask.Result.ToSelectList("Id", "Name", BaseCurrencyId);
        ViewBag.RemittanceCurrency = remittanceCurrencyTask.Result.ToSelectList("Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.BranchRemittanceCountry = branchRemiCountryTask.Result.ToSelectList("Id", "Name");
}

private async Task<List<Lookup>> GetBaseCurrencyAsync()
{
     return (await _lookupService.GetAllAsync(new LookupRequest() { Type = LookupType.BaseCurrency, ParentId = CountryId.ToString() })).ToList();
}

private async Task<List<Lookup>> GetRemittanceCurrencyAsync()
{
    return (await _lookupService.GetAllAsync(new LookupRequest() { Type = LookupType.TransactionCurrency, ParentId = CountryId.ToString() })).ToList();
}

private async Task<List<Lookup>> GetBranchRemCountryAsync()
{
    return (await _lookupService.GetAllAsync(new LookupRequest() { Type = LookupType.Country, ParentId = "" })).ToList();
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
 public async Task LoadDDL()
    {
        var baseCurrencyTask = GetBaseCurrencyAsync();
        var remittanceCurrencyTask = GetRemittanceCurrencyAsync();
        var branchRemiCountryTask = GetBranchRemCountryAsync();
        await Task.WhenAll(baseCurrencyTask, remittanceCurrencyTask, branchRemiCountryTask);
        ViewBag.BaseCurrency = (await baseCurrencyTask).ToSelectList("Id", "Name", BaseCurrencyId);
        ViewBag.RemittanceCurrency = (await remittanceCurrencyTask).ToSelectList("Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.BranchRemittanceCountry = (await branchRemiCountryTask).ToSelectList("Id", "Name");
    }
```

**For .ToSelectList** extention method

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this List<T> list, string idPropertyName, string namePropertyName = "Name", object defaultValue = null)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        var selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

        if (list is null)
        {
            return selectListItems;
        }
        list.ForEach(item => selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = item.GetType().GetProperty(namePropertyName).GetValue(item).ToString(),
            Value = item.GetType().GetProperty(idPropertyName).GetValue(item).ToString(),
            Selected = defaultValue != null && item.GetType().GetProperty(idPropertyName).GetValue(item).ToString() == defaultValue.ToString()
        }));

        return selectListItems;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please assist here? Is there something I am missing or what?

Comment: Why are you using `.Result` inside an async method?

Comment: @Llama Because he awaits them in batch, and the result is already there

Comment: What does `.ToSelectList(` return?

Comment: _it doesn't load last view bag_ - what you mean? How you know it is not loading?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Ah, my eyes managed to somehow gloss over that line. My bad.

Comment: Why not do the `.ToSelectList` within each task?

Comment: Can you elaborate on *it doesn't load last view bag*? Are they ViewBag properties null?

Comment: Q: What is meaning of not loading : Answer: In rendered html i don't get data

Comment: .ToSelectList is custom extension method  for rendering ListItem

Comment: I have included SelectList Extension method code as well

Comment: @Fabio
There are there values when it renders in HTML it only has data for 1st two ViewBags and 3rd is empty While if i debug the code it works fine

Comment: That `.ToSelectList` method is terrible. Just use this `SelectList` constructor instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_Object_ it will perform better.

Comment: Is your `_lookupService` querying a sql database? Does your connection string allow multiple result sets?

Comment: _Answer: In rendered html i don't get data_ - Did you check rendered html in debug session as well?

Comment: @jeremy-lakeman this service is getting data from Rest Api

Answer (score 0):

`await` can be used on the same task multiple times. Only the first time will actually wait for it to finish. So instead of calling `.Result`, try getting the results like

```
(await branchRemiCountryTask).ToSelectList(...);
```

Comment: I did that too and still it doesn't work .. Let me update question as well